# PHP preg_replace - удалить родительский div (wp)

Tags: php, wordpress

В выводе текста записи (wordpress) есть:

```html
   <div itemprop="author" itemscope="" itemengine="http://schema.org/Organization">
      <li>...</li>
   </div>
```

Нужно получить следующее:

```html
      <li>...</li>
```

Пробую так:

```php
   $content = preg_replace('/<div itemprop="author"\s.+?>(.*?)<\/div>/i', '$1', $content);
```

но результат не утешительный... пожалуйста, подскажите, что не так?
Всем добра!

**UPD:**
@noname228 поделился рабочим вариантом
`preg_replace('/(<div\b[^><]*)>/i', '', $content);` - но данный код потрет все `<div>` в строке... есть идеи как его правильно ориентировать на `<div itemprop="author" ...`?

Comment: Я для подобной задачи просто писал скрипт и с помощью https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io прогонял все посты и обратно сохранял в базу.

Comment: Да я хотел простого решения задачи, думал, в 1 строку это пофиксить... не тут-то было. Большое спасибо за совет! Все же хочу понять, где я ошибся...

Comment: `.+` - любое количество символов. `>` тоже символ.

Comment: @u_mulder спасибо за поправку!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Патерн, который соответствует div-элементам, с атрибутами itemprop="author".

```
$content = preg_replace('#<div[^>]+\bitemprop="author"[^>]*>\s*(.*?)\s*</div>#sui', "$1", $content);
```

Comment: Приветствую! Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ - это рабочее решение!